# Organizing and grouping sophisticated processes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As an example, lets say I have 4 models: `Product`, `Order`, `Customer`, `Store`

When an `order` is placed by a `customer` in a `store`, the store's owner would get an email asking to confirm the UPC code on the `product`. Once confirmed, the customer would get an email with a code that when they enter it into their portal, it activates the `product`.

There is a lot of logic here, which spans several models. For example, when the `order` is completed, it creates a new inactive `product` with a confirmation key. The store owner accesses this `product` by its confirmation key and adds the upc information to it. Only then, once the `product` has upc information can the customer confirm it.

**TL;DR** - My question is, what is the best way to group a large process, which involves many models, into a central location? Instead of accessing several other models from within one model, it would make more sense to have it centralized. Is there a best-practice for this type of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is typically going to result in a "Service Object" that would be placed in `/lib`.

This allows for testing the workflow in isolation and doesn't fatten up models unnecessarily.

You can find a good intro to Service Objects here:

- https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services
- http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/06/02/anatomy-of-service-objects-in-rails/